# Cauchy - Schwarz inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $x,y,z,t$ real numbers such that $x^2+y^2=z^2+t^2$. Then find the supremum of $(20yz+14yt+20xt-14xz)/(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)$ over $x,y,z,t$.

When I apply Cauchy- Schwarz directly there are some wrong results. The problem is when equality holds? I know it is easy problem but every time saw only $(+)$ signs in inequalities (whenever to solve problems with Cauchy inequality)

Answer (score 0):

One might see components of a product of complex numbers in the numerator. Try multiplying out
\begin{align}
-(14+20i)(x+iy)(z+it)
&=-(14+20i)((xz-yt)+i(xt+yz))\\[1em]
&=14(yt-xz)+20(xt+yz)\\
&\qquad-i\bigl(14(xt+yz)+20(xz-yt)\bigr)
\end{align}
so the numerator is the real part of this triple product. The denominator is by assumption 
$$
|x+iy|^2+|z+it|^2=2|x+iy|^2=2|(x+iy)(z+it)|.
$$ 
Thus one gets a maximal quotient of $\frac{Re(a·b)}{2|b|}$ when $b=(x+iy)(z+it)$ is a multiple with positive factor of $a^*=-(14+20i)^*=-14+20i$. The maximal value of
$$
\frac{-Re\Bigl((14+20i)·[(x+iy)(z+it)]\Bigr)}{2|(x+iy)(z+it)|}
$$ 
is then $\frac12|-14+20i|=|-7+10i|$.

Comment: But i got $\sqrt(298)$ by using Cauchy. Did i miss smthng or you ?

Comment: But can you solve $(xt,yz,yt,xz)=\lambda(20,20,14,-14)$, implying $20^2=-14^2$? You can use $a=xt+yz$ and $b=yt-xz$ and find that $a^2+b^2=(x^2+y^2)(z^2+t^2)$, and $(a,b)=\lambda(20,14)$ can be easily solved using $(z,t)=(0,1)$.

Comment: $(20yz+14yt+20xt-14xz)^2/(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)\leq [400y^2+196t^2+400x^2+196z^2]=596(x^2+y^2)=298(x^2+y^2+z^2+t^2)$ then get result

Comment: Then for the equality in the bound you need to solve $(20y,14t, 20x, -14z)= λ·(z,y,t,x)$ with a real factor $λ$. The round-trip gives $λ^4 = -14^2·20^2$, which again is impossible.

Comment: Sir your solution is powerful technique. Ok i agree with you. But how can we apply well-known Cauchy? It is impossible?

Comment: In the second comment I give the interpretation $\frac{20a+14b}{2\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ which using Cauchy takes its supremum for $(a,b)=(10,7)$ or a multiple which can be realized using $(x,y)=(10,7)$, $(z,t)=(0,\sqrt{149})$. -- Which essentially is the same as the answer, as $(w,z)=Re(w^*z)$ is a scalar product on $\Bbb C$.